# How to do aggregation on sql joins?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables

EXE1 (Folder,report)

```
FOLDER | REPORT
Axis  | Savings
Axis  | Deposit
Icici | credit
Icici | debit 
Axis  | Savings
```

EXE2 (Folder,report)

```
FOLDER | REPORT
Axis  | Savings
Axis  | Deposit
Icici | credit
Icici | debit 
Axis  | deposit
Icici | credit
```

I need count of report by joining two tables

What I have tried

```sql
Select exe1.folder,exe1.report,count(exe1.report) e1,count(exe2.report)e2
From Exe1 
  join Exe2 On exe1.folder=exe2.folder 
   And exe1.report=exe2.report
Where exe1.report='savings'
group by exe1.folder,exe1.report
```

This gives output

```
Folder | Report |e1 | e2
Axis   | Savings|2  | 2
```

But I need

```
Folder | Report |e1 | e2
Axis   | Savings|2  | 1
```

Can someone tell me how to get the results and how to handle such scenarios.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand `count()`.  It counts the number of rows with non-null values for the expression.  That is why the two values are the same.  You can fix your logic using `count(distinct)`:

```
select exe1.folder, exe1.report, count(distinct exe1.report) as e1,
       count(distinct exe2.report) as e2
from Exe1 join
     Exe2
     on exe1.folder = exe2.folder and exe1.report = exe2.report
where exe1.report='savings'
group by exe1.folder, exe1.report;
```

This is probably not the most efficient way of solving your problem.  But if your counts are small, then the performance penalty is not really bad.  It is usually better to use correlated subqueries or aggregate *before* joining.

Comment: But report isn't distinct. It can repeat n number of times. Please check my inputs @Gordon.

Comment: @user9208802 . . . `count()` the primary key in `exe2`.

Comment: @Gordon...how do you validate your code? Is there some online tool that can do this for you?  I see a lot of questions that seem very interesting, but there is no 'CREATE TABLE...' and 'INSERT INTO...', etc, etc.  Do you type out all this code yourself and answer countless questions, or do you just look at the questions, and you automatically know what to do?  Don't you need the CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO?  Just curious.  Thanks.

Comment: @ASH . . . For most questions, I read the question and see the SQL.

Comment: That's awesome!!